# Unable to access my webserver (virtual machine, Ubuntu 14.10) through browser

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have setup a Virtual Machine on my Windows 7 system (Ubuntu 14.10). It looks like Apache, MySql and PHP have been installed successfully. If I ran

```
curl -l 127.0.0.1
```

I see the website in my console.
But if I hit this address in my browser I just get "This web page is not available".

VM->Settings->Network: I've selected "Bridged Adapter".

Have anyone any ideas what could cause the issue? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to access to it with 127.0.0.1 ? If yes it can't work. You have to use the VM ip.

Comment: Hey Kirito. Yes! I tried 127.0.0.1. How do I get the VM ip? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to access to 127.0.0.1 it's not gonna work. You have two solutions :

- With a bridged interface, go to ubuntu, open a terminal and type `ifconfig` (it's possible you have to be root for that). Then use the ip displayed.
- You can add an host only interface and do the same thing